# why do i need to append .default after import statement

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I am following laracast's vue2 step by step series. On lesson 26 that describes basics of vue router, the router file is defined as below:

```
//file: routes.js
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Home from './Views/Home.vue';
import About from './Views/About.vue';
const routes = [
 {
  path: '/',
  component: require('./Views/Home.vue')
 },
]

export default new VueRouter ({
 routes
});

//file: Home.vue

<template>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Home Page</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    I'm an example component.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

I was getting an error that `Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.`

Some googling revealed the solution that i need to change the component property like this:

```
component: require('./Views/About.vue').default
```

That is i need to append **.default**.

I would like someone to explain why and may be route me to some resource for more details.

Could i have done it in some other way, like adding an export statement in my Home.vue file? If so, what would be correct syntax.

Thanks

Comment: I thought `component: () => import('./Views/About.vue')` is more popular to use.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Description

Comment: Can you specify which line exactly throws the error? And which file - router or app?

Comment: @Skipper: the line that throws the error is `component: require('./Views/Home.vue')` , which is in the file **router.js**
As i said already, appending `.default` to this line solves it.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I don't know why you would do this instead of clear and working way:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Home from './Views/Home.vue';
import About from './Views/About.vue';
const routes = [
 {
  path: '/',
  component: Home
 },
]

export default new VueRouter ({
 routes
});
```

Comment: usually i would do the way that you showed here. But i was curious to know how the other way works as i saw people doing it like that somewhere. Would be good to learn something new.